# how to install tgcil EST assembler on ubuntu

Tags: assembler

I downloaded TGICL-2.1.tar.gz  file  from [sourcforge](https://www.google.nl/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCIQFjAAahUKEwi9qp3osMTHAhXMvRoKHaGRBP0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsourceforge.net%2Fprojects%2Ftgicl%2Ffiles%2Ftgicl%2520v2.1%2F&ei=NnPcVb23Msz7aqGjkugP&usg=AFQjCNGXyOwXTYo0vWRzRm6UiKeG1JSGIA&sig2=GARExavUeVyKX0TFCfZ45g).

and  I extract  the file. Then I want to install TGICL but I don't know how to do.

Someone please help me.

Comment: For which Ubuntu release?

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the archive

   ```
   tar xf TGICL-2.1.tar.gz
   cd TGICL-2.1
   ```
2. Build

   ```
   ./Build.PL
   ./Build
   ```
3. Test

   ```
   ./Build test
   ```

   Sample output

   ```
   t/00-load.t .. Use of :locked is deprecated at /home/aboettger/Downloads/TGICL-2.1/blib/lib/TGI/DBDrv.pm line 36.
   t/00-load.t .. 1/6 # Testing TGI::Util 0.01, Perl 5.020002, /usr/bin/perl
   t/00-load.t .. ok   
   All tests successful.
   Files=1, Tests=6,  1 wallclock secs ( 0.02 usr  0.01 sys +  0.04 cusr  0.00 csys =  0.07 CPU)
   Result: PASS
   ```
4. Install

   ```
   sudo ./Build install
   ```